# Calculating rowSums by group with dynamic column names

Tags: r, data.table, reshape, dcast

I would like to calculate the share of production of each fossil fuel by the drilling type used in the production.
Starting point is the following data.table

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(Global.Company.Key = c(1380L, 1380L, 1380L, 1380L, 1380L)
                     , Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter = structure(c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000), class = "yearqtr")
                     , Current.Assets.Total = c(2218, 2218, 2218, 2218, 2218)
                     , DRILL_TYPE = c("U", "D", "V", "H", "U")
                     , DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter = c(18395.6792379842, 1301949.24041659, 235.311086392291, 27261.8049684835, 4719.27956989249)
                     , DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter = c(1600471.27107983, 4882347.22928982, 2611.60215053765, 9634.76418242493, 27648.276603634)), .Names = c("Global.Company.Key", "Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter", "Current.Assets.Total", "DRILL_TYPE", "DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter",  "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table",  "data.frame"), sorted = c("Global.Company.Key",  "Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter"))
```

I can then calculate the total of the production for each of the two fossil fuel types, based on the drilling type.

```
# Oil Production per Drilling Type and Total Sum
dcast(dt, Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE , value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter"), fun = list(sum))[, Total.Sum :=rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), by=.(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter), .SDcols=c("U","D", "V", "H")][]

# Gas Production per Drilling Type and Total Sum
dcast(dt, Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE , value.var =  c("DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"), fun = list(sum))[, Total.Sum :=rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), by=.(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter), .SDcols=c("U","D", "V", "H")][]
# Combined calculation of the production for both fossil fuels with dynamic naming.
dcast(dt, Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE , value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"), fun = list(sum))[, Total.Sum :=rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), by=.(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter)][]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to calculate the total sum grouped for the different fossil fuel types? As you can see in the last case of the `dcast` command it concatenates the names of the new columns, therefore making it impossible to group the columns, by selecting the columns directly.

Basically, I would like to get the output of the last example, although enhanced by additional columns with a sum for the total oil and gas production.
I would then would like to use these sums to to calculate the share of oil and gas production coming from one of the four well types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative approach using `data.table` and `dcast()` which is about twice as fast as OP's merge [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43000219/3817004)

#### Complete the reshape from wide to long

```
molten <- melt(dt, measure.vars = patterns("^DI"))
molten
#    Global.Company.Key Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter Current.Assets.Total DRILL_TYPE            variable        value
# 1:               1380                           2000                 2218          U DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter   18395.6792
# 2:               1380                           2000                 2218          D DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter 1301949.2404
# 3:               1380                           2000                 2218          V DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter     235.3111
# 4:               1380                           2000                 2218          H DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter   27261.8050
# 5:               1380                           2000                 2218          U DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter    4719.2796
# 6:               1380                           2000                 2218          U DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter 1600471.2711
# 7:               1380                           2000                 2218          D DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter 4882347.2293
# 8:               1380                           2000                 2218          V DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter    2611.6022
# 9:               1380                           2000                 2218          H DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter    9634.7642
#10:               1380                           2000                 2218          U DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter   27648.2766
```

#### Compute totals

```
totals <- molten[, .(DRILL_TYPE = "Total.Sum", value = sum(value)), 
                 by = .(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter, 
                        Current.Assets.Total, variable)]
totals
#   Global.Company.Key Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter Current.Assets.Total            variable DRILL_TYPE   value
#1:               1380                           2000                 2218 DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter  Total.Sum 1352561
#2:               1380                           2000                 2218 DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter  Total.Sum 6522713
```

#### Append totals to details

```
molten <- rbind(molten, totals)
molten
#    Global.Company.Key Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter Current.Assets.Total DRILL_TYPE            variable        value
# 1:               1380                           2000                 2218          U DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter   18395.6792
# 2:               1380                           2000                 2218          D DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter 1301949.2404
# 3:               1380                           2000                 2218          V DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter     235.3111
# 4:               1380                           2000                 2218          H DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter   27261.8050
# 5:               1380                           2000                 2218          U DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter    4719.2796
# 6:               1380                           2000                 2218          U DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter 1600471.2711
# 7:               1380                           2000                 2218          D DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter 4882347.2293
# 8:               1380                           2000                 2218          V DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter    2611.6022
# 9:               1380                           2000                 2218          H DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter    9634.7642
#10:               1380                           2000                 2218          U DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter   27648.2766
#11:               1380                           2000                 2218  Total.Sum DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter 1352561.3153
#12:               1380                           2000                 2218  Total.Sum DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter 6522713.1433
```

#### Reshape from long to wide

```
# reorder factor levels of DRILL_TYPE to ensure 
# that columns are in the same order as rows (with totals last)
molten[, DRILL_TYPE := forcats::fct_inorder(DRILL_TYPE)]
# reshape
    dcast(molten, ... ~ variable + DRILL_TYPE, sum, value.var = "value")
#   Global.Company.Key Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter Current.Assets.Total DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter_U DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter_D
#1:               1380                           2000                 2218              23114.96               1301949
#   DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter_V DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter_H DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter_Total.Sum DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter_U DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter_D
#1:              235.3111               27261.8                       1352561               1628120               4882347
#   DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter_V DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter_H DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter_Total.Sum
#1:              2611.602              9634.764                       6522713
```

The result is similar to the one created with OP's `merge()` approach (except for column order).

#### Benchmarking

```
mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  merge = merge(
    x = dcast(
      dt,
      Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE ,
      value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"),
      fun = list(sum)
    )[, -grepl(glob2rx("DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter_*"), colnames(
      dcast(
        dt,
        Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE ,
        value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"),
        fun = list(sum)
      )
    )), with = FALSE][, DI.Oil.Prod.Total.Sum := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), by =
                        .(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter)][]
    ,
    y = dcast(
      dt,
      Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE ,
      value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"),
      fun = list(sum)
    )[, -grepl(glob2rx("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter_*"), colnames(
      dcast(
        dt,
        Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE ,
        value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"),
        fun = list(sum)
      )
    )), with = FALSE][, DI.Gas.Prod.Total.Sum := rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), by =
                        .(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter)][]
    ,
    all.x = TRUE
    ,
    by = c(
      "Global.Company.Key",
      "Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter",
      "Current.Assets.Total"
    )
  ),
  aggr = {
    molten <- melt(dt, measure.vars = patterns("^DI"))
    molten[, Total.Sum := sum(value), by = .(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter, Current.Assets.Total, variable)]
    dcast(molten, ... ~ variable + DRILL_TYPE, sum, value.var = "value")
    molten <- melt(dt, measure.vars = patterns("^DI"))
    molten <- rbind(molten, molten[, .(DRILL_TYPE = "Total.Sum", value = sum(value)), 
                                   by = .(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter, 
                                          Current.Assets.Total, variable)])
    molten[, DRILL_TYPE := forcats::fct_inorder(DRILL_TYPE)]
    dcast(molten, ... ~ variable + DRILL_TYPE, sum, value.var = "value")
  },
  times = 100L
)
```

Note that the merge approach needs about three times as much lines of code. Also performance is twice as slow as the *aggregate and rbind* approach.

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 merge 20.298773 21.181559 22.13640 21.77682 22.59126 26.22265   100
  aggr  9.393847  9.806165 10.33053 10.07595 10.35460 20.11112   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want but like this?:

`dt %>% group_by(DRILL_TYPE) %>% summarise(so=sum(DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter),sg=sum(DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter),tot=so+sg)`

**EDIT**

Now summarizing over duplicate entries and using dcast to create a single row

```
dt %>% 
gather(variable, value, -(Global.Company.Key:DRILL_TYPE)) %>%
unite(temp, DRILL_TYPE, variable) %>% dcast(... ~ temp, fun=sum,drop=FALSE) %>%
mutate(so=sum(select(dt,contains("Oil"))),sg=sum(select(dt,contains("Gas"))),tot=so+sg)
```

Comment: Thanks, it should look like the output of the last `dcast`, but with two additonal columns summing up the total production of oil and gas.

Comment: The code is not working with the total sum. I think you'll need to add the individual `sum` functions in the total, since `so` and `sg` are not properly defined.

Comment: (late response, was gone for a while) I am not sure but your sum (e.g. oil.prod.total.sum) is not the sum of the quarters if I calculate it. I figured out a way to do it using tidyr which I think works best. The difficult bit was fixing the duplicate entries which are now summed using dcast. (see edit)

Comment: What packages did you load in which order?

Comment: just the data.table (used for the dt/dcast) and tidyverse. Just changed the mutate part to a slightly better form.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an answer, although it's probably inefficent as hell, but it gives the desired output.

```
merge(x = dcast(dt, Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE , value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"), fun = list(sum) )[, -grepl(glob2rx("DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter_*"), colnames(dcast(dt, Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE , value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"), fun = list(sum) ))), with = FALSE][, DI.Oil.Prod.Total.Sum :=rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), by=.(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter)][]
      , y = dcast(dt, Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE , value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"), fun = list(sum) )[, -grepl(glob2rx("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter_*"), colnames(dcast(dt, Global.Company.Key + Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter + Current.Assets.Total  ~ DRILL_TYPE , value.var =  c("DI.Oil.Prod.Quarter", "DI.Gas.Prod.Quarter"), fun = list(sum) ))), with = FALSE][, DI.Gas.Prod.Total.Sum :=rowSums(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), by=.(Global.Company.Key, Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter)][]
      , all.x = TRUE
      , by = c( "Global.Company.Key", "Calendar.Data.Year.and.Quarter", "Current.Assets.Total")
)
```